# Rails 3 Showing image_tag with different style with if statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, coding-style

I am trying to change the style of an image created with image_tag. Below is my current code.

```
        <% if @user.image? %>
            <%= link_to image_tag(@user.image_url(:medium), :style => "width:717px;height:409px"),
                        @user.image_url(:medium1024), :rel => "facebox" %>

            <% else %>

            <%= image_tag 'i.jpg', :style => "width:717px;height:409px" %>
        <% end %>
```

I want to be able to change the `:style => "width:717px;height:409px"` to `:style => ""` dependent on whether `@user.machine` is imac, macbookpro, pc or laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have set up @user.machine in your controller I would use the image_tag to create a class based on the value of machine. If I were you I would simply create css classes that correspond to @user.machine's values so you can link them up like this:

```
<%= link_to image_tag(@user.image_url(:medium), :class => "#{@user.machine}") %>
```

This will spit out HTML like this (depending on what @user.machine is set to:

```
<img class="macbookpro" src="imageurl" />
```